# How to fix failing cumulative update on Windows 10 Pro (1909) upgraded from Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1909

I am seeing error 0x80070003 in CBS.log after consistently failing to install the cumulative update for February 2020 (KB4532693).

The logged error is always:

```
2020-03-06 21:29:44, Error                 CBS    Shtd: Failed while processing non-critical driver operations queue. [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
```

... where `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` is the corresponding Win32 error code (3) translated to `HRESULT`.

The corresponding error in `%WINDIR%\inf\setupapi.dev.log` looks like this:

```
>>>  [Install Driver Updates]
>>>  Section start 2020/03/06 21:29:43.850
      cmd: C:\WINDOWS\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.651_none_5f2896f458eff373\TiWorker.exe -Embedding
     sto: Image State        = Specialized
     sto: Image Architecture = amd64
     sto: Image OS Version   = 10.0.18363
     sto: Image Product Type = WinNT
     sto: Transaction        = CbsDriversAndPrimitives
     sto: Driver Updates     = 644
!    inf: Unable to load INF: 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d\netathrx.inf'(00000003)
!!!  inf: Invalid INF 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d\netathrx.inf', parsing error on line 0. Code = 1002
!!!  sto: Failed to get version info for driver update 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d\netathrx.inf'. Error = 0x00000003
<<<  Section end 2020/03/06 21:29:44.069
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x00000003)]
```

So it seems I am looking for a file named `C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d\netathrx.inf`. The folder that is supposed to contain this file doesn't exist. The slight problem are the permissions (ACL) on the parent folder, though. Surprisingly the file `netathrx.inf` exists in `%WINDIR%\INF`.

There is indeed an Qualcomm Atheros network adapter in this laptop:

> Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter

My question now: how do I find that file and replace it in hopes of the update installation succeeding after that?

Note: right now I've tried everything from installing the (cumulative) update manually using `dism /online` with and without giving a mounted `install.wim` as `/source` and I also used `sfc /scannow` (which found and fixed *one* issue, but after that point never reported anything again). So I am at a loss as to what non-destructive action I can take short of using the "repair" feature from the Windows 10 installation media, which I fear would reset stuff in the registry and thus could affect installed programs.

---

I have no third-party AV/AM solution, instead using the Windows Defender suite of applications.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter in question which seems to cause the update installation to require `netathrx.inf` reports with `lspci` (on Linux) as:

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

The way I chose to investigate the issue was as follows:

1. download a pristine copy of "Windows 10" using the media creation tool from Microsoft
2. extract the matching Windows as `install.wim` from `install.esd`
3. mount that (`dism /mount-image /imagefile:install.wim /index:1 /mountdir:%CD%\mount /readonly`)
4. check the contents of `System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d\netathrx.inf` and `INF\netathrx.inf` relative to the mount point
5. copy the files from the previous point into some temporary location
6. unmount the `install.wim`, discarding all possible changes (`dism /unmount-image /mountdir:%CD%\mount /discard`)

The findings from this were as follows:

4. the files in the two locations seemed to be identical and hardlinked to the same content (as can often be seen with SxS also)
5. computing the digests over the contents of the files proved the fact that they were identical (they were also identical to the one existing in `%SystemRoot%\INF`)

> #### For reference
>
> For reference I am giving the SHA-2 and SHA-1 of the `netathrx.inf`:
>
> ```
> 77dde20a2eed36696f2f5e036a838ff0fbc45dec33ad7647c789397c96553240  netathrx.inf
> 5a57d3a77021e14bec535dbe2d05ee734ec36dd0  netathrx.inf
> ```

After verifying these things the path to fixing this immediate issue seemed clear (although I did not know at the point whether a bigger issue would be hiding behind this one).

Due to the restrictive ACL of the `%SystemRoot%\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository` I opted to "abuse" [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to impersonate `SYSTEM` (aka LocalSystem). This can be done - from an elevated prompt - by executing `psexec -sid %COMSPEC%` (or even `psexec -sid cmd.exe`).

This way I was now able (current working directory was `%SystemRoot%`) to make the directory for the missing INF file:

```
md System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d
```

after that I simply hardlinked the file in place:

```
mklink /h System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d\netathrx.inf INF\netathrx.inf
```

Without reboot I was able to initiate another attempt of installing said cumulative update and reboot to see it succeed.

And indeed it succeeded this time.

Hope this detailed description helps others to resolve similar issues. It's unfortunately a highly manual process and I was surprised to see that `dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth`, `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` didn't report or fix the issue.

**NOTE:** please be aware that inside the `install.wim` the folder `netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d` contains more files than just the INF. I suspect that it would make sense to copy (or hardlink if they exist elsewhere) the files for other scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

I (and a few [other](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/when-certain-windows-monthly-quality-updates-failed-with/td-p/3847141) people) got the same exact problem last month. The error the UI throws is just a very bland message: "Some update files are missing or have problems. We'll try to download the update again later."

I'm appalled that there's no practical way to fix the driver store, but anyway I fixed this with [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

```
psexec -i -d -s xcopy %WINDIR%\WinSxS\amd64_dual_netathrx.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_aca2c01a764c25fb\ %WINDIR%\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netathrx.inf_amd64_220db23f5419ea8d\
```

Comment: You should document the process that made you determine it was this specific inf file blocking the update

Comment: It's literally the one OP wrote. I just searched for it on my disk, and found the exact same version in another package.